# Why is my image not recognized by the facebook OpenGraph API (og:image)?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am developing a website ( https://last-mail.org ) and am trying to hook it up to Facebook's Open Graph API to have nice information and an image show when people share it on Facebook.

However, Facebook keeps complaining that something is wrong with my image:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=last-mail.org

telling me that `Provided og:image could not be downloaded or is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'https://last-mail.org/images/forgetmenotlogo5.png' will be used instead.`

I know:

- The image is 1200px x 900px
- I've tried both .jpg and .png formats
- I've tried hosting it on the https:// (private_html) part of the site, as well as on the http:// (public_html) part of the site
- It does show up in the previews on the OpenGraph debugger tool page.
- Browsers have no problem with displaying the image.

Why is this image rejected? How can I fix this?

Comment: The link you provided is not working

Comment: Hmm... it seems that Facebook for some reason does not want people to hotlink it. Oddly enough they do keep the link in the URL. Just click the 'debug' button on the page, and the results will show.

Comment: I don't see any warning there